# create an integer array and accessing the fourth element of it

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

i just started learning javascript and i have a task for tomorrow to create a simple integer array and accesing the fourth element of it
Please take into consideration my task

Answer (score 0):

```js
// create an array
const array = [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999]

// access the fourth element with the index 3. Indexing starts from 0
const fourthElement = array[3]

// output - '444'
console.log(fourthElement)
```

Comment: why the array must be constant?

Comment: why i cant declare it as a number

Comment: it doesn't have to be constant. even so, you can still add and remove items to it. array and number are two different things.